# Snipping Tool zoomed by itself

Tags: snipping

I have an issue with my snipping tools where it is zoomed in when i clicked New snip.

Why is that and is there a way to fix?
When i clicked New snip, it is only 1/4 of the screen and zoomed in.

I am on windows 10.
Thank you and regards.

Comment: Could you perhaps provide a screenshot?

Comment: Well , im not sure how to add a screenshot if my screenshots is 25% of my screen....

Comment: Sorry , maybe i choose the wrong word. The snipping tools Auto-Snip , 25% of my screen , which is 1/4 of the whole screen. If you divide the screen in a cut of 4 like a cake , it is the top left side.